# Drag and drop columns in a table with angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I need to move the columns of a table, but I do not know which component to use or how to implement it, could you recommend one and how to do it?

basically this is my component.html

```
<form>
<table class="table-fixed">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngIf="selectionMode == 'multi'" class="checkbox">
      <mat-checkbox (change)="onChangeSelectionAll($event)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <th *ngFor="let column of columns" class="pointer" (click)="sort(column)">{{column.label}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let node of data">
    <td>
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="node.isSelected" name="node.id" (change)="onChangeSelection($event, node)" [ngClass]="node.isFiltered ? 'filtered' : ''">
      </mat-checkbox>

    </td>
    <td *ngIf="showIcon" class="icon" (click)="onClicked($event, node)">
      <i class="icon-{{node.data.iconname ? node.data.iconname.toLowerCase().replace('.png', '') : ''}}" height="24"></i>
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="showStatus" class="icon">
      <i *ngIf="node.tooltip !== '<ul></ul>'" tooltip-delay="300" tooltip='{{ node.tooltip }}' tooltip-position="right" class="material-icons {{node.icon_class}}"
        height="24">{{node.icon}}</i>
      <i *ngIf="node.tooltip === '<ul></ul>'" class="material-icons {{node.icon_class}}" height="24">{{node.icon}}</i>
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let column of columns" class="{{(node.normalizedError && node.normalizedError[column.id]) ? 'error' : 'normal'}}"
      tooltip="{{(node.normalizedError && node.normalizedError[column.id]) ? node.normalizedError[column.id] : false}}"
      tooltip-delay="300" tooltip-position="below" tooltipDisabled="{{(node.normalizedError && node.normalizedError[column.id]) ? false : true}}"
      (click)="onClicked($event, node)" [innerHTML]="node.normalizedData[column.name.toLowerCase()] ? node.normalizedData[column.name.toLowerCase()] : ''"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<!--</div>-->
</table>
</form>
```

how can i move the columns?

Comment: I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236058/angular-material-table-drag-and-drop-columns-with-sorting-not-wroking Give the man some love.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge you can achieve this by either of the following ways -

1. Refer this https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview
   you can use this Angular material framework and by using the cdkDropListDropped event

2.As mentioned by @Gaurav ,you can use https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/colreorder

3.If you dont want to use any additional framework , you can achieve it as follows -

// in html

```
   <th *ngFor="let t of tableHeader;index as i" draggable="true" (dragstart)="dragStartColumn(i)"
          (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (drop)="dropColumn(i)""></th>
```

// in ts

An array move function that will remove the dragged column from its index and put it at the index that we want.

```
public arrayMove(arr, from, to) {
    let cutOut = arr.splice(from, 1)[0]; // remove the dragged element at index 'from'
    arr.splice(to, 0, cutOut);            // insert it at index 'to'
  }
```

// and the drag events

```
  public dragStartColumn(index) {
    this.draggedColumnIndex = index;
  }

  public allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  public dropColumn(index) {
    this.arrayMove(this.tableHeader, this.draggedColumnIndex, index);
  }
```

Thats it! Now your columns are draggable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use primeng component for datatable and it has feature to re order columns. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/colreorder