# Angular Material table drag and drop columns with sorting not wroking

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

The angular material table with sorting doesn't work properly with drag-and-drop.

Here's what I've got so far, it kinda works where the sorting works with a specific column after being dragged and dropped. But still has weird functionality.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-columns-draggable)

I want to be able to use the normal sorting functionality of [Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table) while being able to drag and drop columns.

Comment: Drag and drop isn't working on the stackblitz. I think your stackblitz needs a theme (e.g. add `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` to `styles.css`) and `hammerjs` (`import 'hammerjs';` in `app.component.ts`)

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz with your recommendations. Also if you drag the column header then it drags the whole column, there is no dragging on the cells.

Comment: You're the man btw.
Haven't found a sorting for the column yet and your stackblitz worked straight away.
If you mind I posted it on their github as a reference. https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13776

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matSort` needs to be on the `mat-table` element

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" cdkDropListGroup matSort>
```

rather than on the `ng-container`

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" cdkDropListGroup>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="column.field" matSort>
```

Comment: Thank you, completely missed that it was in the ng-container.